# Reducing sequences abab to ab in R

Tags: r, sequence

Looking for flexible solution to reduce sequences

```
'abab' to 'ab' or 
'abcdcded' to 'abcded'
```

but e.g.

```
'abcdefcd'
```

should remain untouched.

However, simplification of

```
'abcabcde' to 'abcde'
```

would be nice as well.

Help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression can refer to capture groups in that same regular expression so that in the following example `"\\2"` refers to the second capture group.

```
x <- c('abab', 'abcdcded', 'abcdefcd', 'abcabcde') # test data

sub("(.*)(.+)\\2(.*)", "\\1\\2\\3", x)
## [1] "ab" "abcded" "abcdefcd" "abcde"
```